# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raise_exception_on_not_ok_status'

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

When I define a function to perform neural network training, I get an error. But, when I do that without making it function, there is no error. Why?

```
def myneural():

    import numpy as np
    import keras
    from keras import backend as K
    from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
    from keras.models import Model, Sequential


    x_train_s = np.random.randint(5, size=(20, 2))
    x_test_s = x_train_s

    model = Sequential([
        Dense(10, input_shape=(2,)),
        Activation('linear'),
        Dense(2),
        Activation('linear')
    ])


    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

    fittingadam = model.fit(x_train_s, x_train_s, epochs=2,
                            validation_data=(x_test_s, x_test_s),
                            shuffle=True, verbose=1, batch_size=None)


    encoder = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                         [model.layers[1].output])

    code = encoder([x_test_s])[0]



myneural()
```

The error I get is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Train on 20 samples, validate on 20 samples
Epoch 1/2
2019-10-03 14:34:50.275279: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2

20/20 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 4.0432 - val_loss: 3.9670
Epoch 2/2

20/20 [==============================] - 0s 53us/step - loss: 3.9670 - val_loss: 3.8917
Exception ignored in: <function BaseSession._Callable.__del__ at 0x0000021A829C1378>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1453, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raise_exception_on_not_ok_status'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But, when I delete the first line and last line and remove indents from other lines, there will be no error.

**First question:** Why is that? How can I resolve it to run it without any problems as a function?

**Second question:** What about the warnings? Are they important? How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should update your tensorflow. If you are already on the newest version (which I doubt), or you are bound by other packages, ignore this Exception. It is a suppressed exception, throw during interpreter cleanup. The fact that you can 'control' wehter or not the exception is thrown is coincidence.
- These are for the people directly using tensorflow, so in your case keras. It's not nice, but you can't do anything about them, except checking if their bug reporter has these warnings already listed.

So in general: As long as it does what you want and has `exit code 0` at the end, ignore all Warnings and Exceptions.